# Why browsers don't find the url in the hosts file?

Tags: php, webserver, hosts

in my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   test1.ru
127.0.0.1   www.test1.ru
```

My broswers(google chrome, firefox) don't find this URL, can't access to this page, after editing the hosts file I've realoaded the browsers(also cleared all the cache), but still no luck why this can be happening?

I'am using denwer... the localhost is loaded succesfully, but sites like http://test1.ru - no luck

any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: And your local server is configured the right way?

Comment: In IE (or Chrome) go to Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings, and uncheck `automatically detect settings`.

Comment: what exactly is the error you get in the browser? this could be either on the side of your DNS resolution (->check if you edited the hosts file with admin right) or a configuration thing in your local webserver

Comment: ipconfig /flushdns - this is what helped my to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing your DNS cache.
Close all browsers.
From the command prompt (as administrator), type:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

This will flush out any cached DNS queries you have in your browsers and operating system.

Comment: GREAT THIS IS WHAT worked thank you very much!, accept in 6 minutes

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  Could you accept this answer as the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but that's the whole idea of that entry.

Setting it to `127.0.0.1` makes that domain point to your local computer, so the browser tries to load the site from your local computer as soon as you try to access `test1.ru`.

Comment: He's having an issue with this setup, but you're correct on the output he's expecting (from what I understand)

Comment: @Ryan Like I said, maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but localhosts and result are exactly what they are supposed to do.

Comment: I think when he says `the localhost is loaded succesfully` he means that when going directly to `localhost` it works, but his host records aren't resolving correctly to localhost.

Comment: This is the reason well written questions are great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the approach.

`Hosts` file is for pointing `DOMAINS(stackoverflow.com, xyz.com, abc.com)` to `SERVERS ADDRESS` just like a `DNS SERVER` would do so.

`test1.ru 127.0.0.1`

OR

`test1.ru $YOURSERVER$`

**NOTE:** To get your server's IP you can `PING` it and you'll know what's your server's IP Address.

Any more questions? Happy to help!